# Appcelerator matrix of views and highlighting the row and column of the view that is clicked

Tags: matrix, view, appcelerator

I am trying to implement a matrix of views in appcelerator.[image]

Some thing like the one i have shown above.
When a user clicks on any of the view, the row and column of views containing that view should be highlighted as well.. Can someone please suggest me an approach in appcelerator code?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you stuck? Some code would be helpful. The problem isn't that complicated.

Create the grid (e.g. with a horizontal layout and with to 20%). Then when you click one item set its background color and border color to a value you like and get its id (e.g. id3). Then you know that you have to set id3, id3+5, id3+5+5,..to be selected (for the vertical row).

You can get the horizontal row by using modulo (e.g. id6 -> 6%5=1 -> row 1 [2nd row]). And select all elements inside this row (row 1 = id6 to id10).

So it is not a Appcelerator problem but just a logic problem. Clicking and changing the elements is possible in Titanium